# Loop until array is empty, condition isn't correct

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays in which I mixed keys and values until one of the arrays is empty. But my loop is execute endless. If key from arrayOne is bigger than arrayTwo. Value is dropped from arrayTwo and added to arrayOne. This is my code

```
$cardsOfPlayerOne = array(
            "karo" => array(
                '1' => 'dwa',
                '2' => 'trzy'
            ),
            "kier" => array(
                '3' => 'dwa',
                '4' => 'trzy'
            ));

$cardsOfPlayerTwo = array(

            "trefl" => array(
                '5' => 'dwa',
                '6' => 'trzy'
            ),
            "pik" => array(
                '7' => 'dwa',
                '8' => 'trzy'
            ));


while (!empty($cardsOfPlayerOne) OR !empty($cardsOfPlayerTwo)){

    $cardKeyOne = array_rand($cardsOfPlayerOne);
    $cardKeyTwo = array_rand($cardsOfPlayerTwo);

    $cardStrenghtOne = array_rand($cardsOfPlayerOne[$cardKeyOne]);
    $cardStrenghtTwo = array_rand($cardsOfPlayerTwo[$cardKeyTwo]);

    if($cardStrenghtOne > $cardStrenghtTwo){

        if(!isset($cardsOfPlayerOne[$cardKeyTwo][$cardStrenghtTwo])){
            $cardsOfPlayerOne[$cardKeyTwo][$cardStrenghtTwo] = array();
        }

        $cardsOfPlayerOne[$cardKeyTwo][$cardStrenghtTwo] = $cardsOfPlayerTwo[$cardKeyTwo][$cardStrenghtTwo];
        unset($cardsOfPlayerTwo[$cardKeyTwo][$cardStrenghtTwo]);


        if(empty($cardsOfPlayerTwo[$cardKeyTwo])){
            unset($cardsOfPlayerTwo[$cardKeyTwo]);
        }

    }
    else{

        if(!isset($cardsOfPlayerTwo[$cardKeyOne][$cardStrenghtOne])){
            $cardsOfPlayerTwo[$cardKeyOne][$cardStrenghtOne] = array();
        }

        $cardsOfPlayerTwo[$cardKeyOne][$cardStrenghtOne] = $cardsOfPlayerOne[$cardKeyOne][$cardStrenghtOne];
        unset($cardsOfPlayerOne[$cardKeyOne][$cardStrenghtOne]);

        if(empty($cardsOfPlayerOne[$cardKeyOne])){
            unset($cardsOfPlayerOne[$cardKeyOne]);
        }


    }



}
```

And code online [LINK](http://ideone.com/bPDMea)

Comment: first of all, tell us what your code supposed to do. without knowing this it's impossible to fix it.

Comment: Should add values from array with smaller key and add to array with bigger key and dropped/unset from array with smaller key . This is works but I want to get out from loop when one of the array will be empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your logic might be incorrect:

```
while (!empty($cardsOfPlayerOne) OR !empty($cardsOfPlayerTwo)){
```

Should be:

```
while (!empty($cardsOfPlayerOne) AND !empty($cardsOfPlayerTwo)){
```

Currently your loop will continue as long as *either* of the two arrays is not empty but as far as I can tell, you would like to exit as soon as one of them *is* empty.